# Do I need an additional hard drive to install Ubuntu on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have a recently built a PC w/ Windows 7 64-bit and I want to run a second drive with Ubuntu on it. I have a 1TB drive. I'm going to install in my computer.

Can I install Ubuntu on the 2nd drive? If that works can I switch between Ubuntu and Windows 7 at startup?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does not need a separate hard drive to be installed on, however, it needs its own partition on a hard drive. When you choose the option "Install alongside Windows" during the Ubuntu setup, your Windows partition will be resized automatically and Ubuntu will place its own partition in the created free space.

Of course, if you wish to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive, this is no problem at all. Just select the second hard drive as the destination drive during the Ubuntu setup.

As a result, you can decide which operating system to boot from the GRUB boot menu, which appears after the BIOS POST.

Comment: i see thats what i was hoping for. because i have 50+ games on steam and i would rather not reinstall all those.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 1TB hard drive, so it's more than enough to handle both operating systems.

Just create another partition and install ubuntu there. Although pretty simple, you can follow  [this tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html) on how to install Ubuntu alongside to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. 1 GB is enough. First make a new partition (min 10 GB,you can choose as your wish) in windows using disk management utility. After installing Ubuntu and restarting PC you will be prompted to Grub boot loader where you can choose Operating system to load.